# Sending PHP values with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to delete images with Ajax and all the php seems to work except when I try to send variables to another php document.

Php that shows and grabs neccessary values.

```
// show images
    $image_display = "";
    foreach(glob($pathimages.'*') as $filename){
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $name_only = basename($filename, ".".$ext);

        $image_display .= "<img src=\"images/" .$targetID."/" .$name_only.".".$ext. "\" width=\"30\" />
                        <a onclick=\"DeleteImage('".$name_only."','".$ext."','".$targetID"'); return false;\" href=\"javascript:;\">X</a>
                        <br />";
        }
```

.JS document, I get the sent and the success messages when pressing the X

```
function DeleteImage(name_only, ext, targetID){
$.ajax({
    url: 'delete_imgs.php',
    type: "POST",
    data:{name_only:name_only,ext:ext,targetID:targetID},
    beforeSend: function() {
    alert("sent");
    },
    success: function(html) {
        alert("Success") 
    },
    error: function( x, status, error ) {
        alert(x.status + status + error);
    }
});
}
```

delete_imgs.php document

```
include('session_check.php');
$name_only = $_POST['name_only'];
$ext = $_POST['ext'];
$targetID = $_POST['targetID'];

$pathimages = "images/$targetID/";

unlink($pathimages . $name_only .".". $ext);
echo "Deleted";
```

Any thoughts are more than welcome since I have banged my brain out of my head by now ...!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try with async:false

```
function DeleteImage(name_only, ext, targetID){
$.ajax({
    url: 'delete_imgs.php',
    type: "POST",
    async : false,
    data:{name_only:name_only,ext:ext,targetID:targetID},
    beforeSend: function() {
    alert("sent");
    },
    success: function(html) {
        alert("Success") 
    },
    error: function( x, status, error ) {
        alert(x.status + status + error);
    }
});
}
```

Maybe that can help

Comment: Sorry!! This acctully seem to have helped a little! When I press the X and then refresh the page the image disappears. Now all I want to do is add so that I don't have to refresh everytime ^^